# Token is showing expired when sending from android

Tags: java, android, node.js, jwt

When I'm sending a token(Bearer) from postman it is working fine. But when I'm sending the same token from the android app and it is showing token is expired but is it fresh and not expired and token is working fine with the postman.

I tried sending a get request without token and it is working fine. The server is running fine the class is working as excepted except authetication.

Node js code for checking the token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const JWT_KEY = require('../../config').getJwtSecrete();

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {

try {
    let token = req.headers.authorization;
    token = getTokenFromHeader(token);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_KEY);
    req.email = decoded.email;
    next();
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Auth failed'
    });
}
};

function getTokenFromHeader(token) {
return token.split(" ")[1];
}
```

Android: My get request method for sending the request

```
public class GET_Request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bundle> {

private static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 10000;
private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
private GETAsyncResponse delegate;

public GET_Request(GETAsyncResponse delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected Bundle doInBackground(String... params) {

    String Url = params[0];
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String result = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;

    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL(Url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
        connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + UserInfo.getToken());
        connection.connect();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HTTP_OK) {

            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            int bisReadResult = bufferedInputStream.read();
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while (bisReadResult != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write((byte) bisReadResult);
                bisReadResult = bufferedInputStream.read();
            }
            result = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        } else { //reading error
            Log.e("doInBackground: ", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));

            String error;
            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            int bisRealError = bufferedInputStream.read();
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while (bisRealError != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write((byte) bisRealError);
                bisRealError = bufferedInputStream.read();
            }
            /*This error string is for debugging*/
            error = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
            Log.e("Error Buffer: ", error);
        }
        bundle.putString(JSON, result);
        bundle.putInt(RESPONSE_CODE, connection.getResponseCode());
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
        bundle.putInt(RESPONSE_CODE, 400);
    }
    /*Internet not connected*/ catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
        bundle.putInt(RESPONSE_CODE, 0);
    }
    /*Any other error*/ catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        bundle.putInt(RESPONSE_CODE, 500);
    }
    return bundle;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    delegate.AfterGetRequestFinish(result);
}

public interface GETAsyncResponse {
    void AfterGetRequestFinish(Bundle bundle);
}
}
```

I want it to authenticate successfully. But I don't know why it is failing and showing code '401' and `'java.io.FileNotFoundException'`.

Comment: Right off the bat, I'm actually going to say here that your Android side Java code is not really relevant to the integrity of the JWT, because it basically doesn't have the ability to tamper with and alter the expiration date.  So, my guess here is that either you are working with a stale token, or you are not using the JWT you think you are.

Comment: Hey, Thanks.

Sorry I did you get you. Can you please explain more?

Comment: I'm saying that you JWT appears to have expired because the token you are passing in fact has already expired.  That is, you're not sending the token you think you are sending.

Comment: Oh man! How could I do that! I wasted my 3 hours figuring out the problem.
And you are right! I tried to log out my new token and it showed my old token.
All look same so I previously tried to log it though it is the same. Thank man!

Comment: No no I'm ok with it. Thanks a lot. Solved it by your comment. :-)

Comment: Should I remove the question because it is stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the features of JWT is that they are essentially tamper-proof.  That is, assuming your suspect JWT has a valid signature and checksum on the Node JS server side, then it means that your Android Java code could not possibly have altered the expiration date of that token.

That being said, the most likely explanation here is that the token you are passing in fact has already expired.  This could come about for a number of reasons, most likely that you have cached an old token somewhere, perhaps in shared preferences.